# How to make xhtml page work with JSF?

Tags: jsf, named

Anyone knows why my xhtml page does not work with its named bean?

I get `Welcome #{indexBean.userName}` in the browser. IndexBean is @Named, @SessionScoped and implements Serializable.

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css"/>
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h2>Welcome #{indexBean.userName}</h2>
</h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
        id="WebApp_ID" 
        version="3.0">

<display-name>WebAdmin</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**Bean**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class IndexBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

**MyFaces**

```
INFO: Reading config : jar:file:/C:/tomee16/lib/openwebbeans-el22-1.2.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
```

Dec 15, 2013 10:27:54 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider getClassloaderFacesConfig
    INFO: Reading config : jar:file:/C:/tomee16/lib/openwebbeans-jsf-1.2.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Dec 15, 2013 10:27:54 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.LogMetaInfUtils logArtifact
    INFO: Artifact 'myfaces-api' was found in version '2.1.13' from path 'file:/C:/tomee16/lib/myfaces-api-2.1.13.jar'
Dec 15, 2013 10:27:54 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.LogMetaInfUtils logArtifact
    INFO: Artifact 'myfaces-impl' was found in version '2.1.13' from path 'file:/C:/tomee16/lib/myfaces-impl-2.1.13.jar'

Comment: Try `@Named("indexBean") @ManagedBean @SesionScoped`

Comment: What address do you request, what version of jsf are you running and where is the managed bean(include the imports)?

Comment: Run as - Run on server gives me this: http://localhost:8080/WebAdmin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XHTML files are only treated as JSF views if you access them via the [FacesServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html). Your `FacesServlet` is mapped to:

```
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
```

So for a file `foo/bar.xhtml` your would have to access it via the URL `http://host/app/faces/foo/bar.xhtml`.

Consider changing the mapping to:

```
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

*Assumes all XHTML files in the app are JSF views.*

Comment: From an example I'm trying to follow, I'd rather use /faces/* mapping.

Comment: I tried mapping you have suggested and it is working. Can you get /faces/ mapping working, as well? I don't think the xhtml file is always known. I plan to have my hotspots as /faces/.

Comment: jacekn, I believe you didn't exactly understood the point of the mapping (let alone how servlets work). Just keep it `*.xhtml`.

Comment: @jacekn In order to be processed by the FacesServlet, the URL you use to access the page must start with `/yourAppContext/faces/...`. The path `/WEB-INF/faces/index.xhtml` does not meet this criteria, for example.

Comment: So I have been thinking about it and maybe *.xhtml will do fine. I was concerned that posting will be affected but in JSF we post to a particular class - to a particular method. So maybe I'm worrying about things that won't come up.

Answer (score 0):

First check the package for the annotations: javax.inject.Named and javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped. Second If you'r using JEE 6 and because you're using CDI, you need to activate the CDI adding the file WEB-INF/beans.xml, this file can be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are calling your page without the FacesServlet handling it.

You should include /faces/ before your page name url

```
localhost:8080/WebAdmin/faces/index.xhtml
```